# How to get value from mysqli_query

Tags: php

I am using mysqli_query

```
SELECT COUNT( statid ) FROM device_realtime_stats
```

In this statement, in db returns some value  ex:3

I want to that integer in php. I am giving like this

```
$rows_count = mysqli_query($con, " SELECT COUNT( statid ) FROM device_realtime_stats ");
```

But it not returns integer, how to convert. I want that integer value in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get count like this

```
// this return mysqli statement not integer
$rows_count = mysqli_query($con, " SELECT COUNT( statid ) as count FROM device_realtime_stats "); 
$count = mysqli_fetch_object($rows_count)->count; // return count as you want
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct way to fetch result. @Mohaideen, note the "as count" statement in SQL query.